# create a file under a directory in multiple machines through some script?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, ansible, ubuntu-14.04

I have to create a file `functon.txt` under a particular directory with `hello world` in it in lots of machine. This is what I was doing so far manually one by one logging into each box and creating the file. That directory is own by `root` so I have to make sure that new file is also owned by `root` user.

```
david@machineA:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for david:
root@machineA:/home/david# cd /opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1
root@machineA:/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1# vi functon.txt
root@machineA:/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1# ssh david@machineB

david@machineB:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for david:
root@machineB:/home/david# cd /opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1
root@machineB:/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1# vi functon.txt
root@machineB:/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1# ssh david@machineC

.....
```

Now I have to do this in around 200 machines. Is there any way I can do these things through some script? I am ok typing passwords multiple times if I have to but I don't want to manually login into those box and do all the other steps by hand.

I have a file `hosts.txt` which contains each machine line by line. I can read this file line by line and do above things but I am not sure how?

This is just one time exercise for me so any easy or simple way should be fine. I can even hardcode my password in the script to do this job. What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you open to a solution using Ansible?

Comment: I guess for `Ansible`, I have to install this on every machines right? And then only it will work? Correct.

Comment: No. Just on one machine. Only requirement is you should be able to `ssh` from that one machine to other machines,

Comment: hmmm I see.. I think that should work then. Can you provide step by step how to do this? I have never used this before so any step by step guidance will help me understand better how to use it.

Comment: Just install `ansible` using `apt-get`. Ansible will copy `functon.txt` from local machine to `/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1/` on target machine. You will give the password only once. I'll post the answer soon. Does the directory `/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1` exist on all machines?

Comment: I see, ok.. Here is the thing, this directory `/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1` might not be there in all the machines. So if this directory is missing in any machine, then I will skip that machine and I won't create the file on that box. Also also print that machine out or anything so that I know in which machine directory is not there.. I mean at the end I want to know which machine doesn't have that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing Ansible:

```
ansible -i /path/to/hosts.txt -m ping -u david --ask-pass all
```

See if you can ping the machines successfully. If it is successful, then try the following with 2 machines (create another txt file with just 2 machines and pass it to `-i` option). Then you can run this for all machines. If the directory does not exist, the command will fail and you will see the failed machines in summary.

```
ansible -i /path/to/hosts.txt -m copy -a "src=/path/to/functon.txt dest=/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1/functon.txt" -u david --ask-pass --become --become-user root --ask-become-pass all
```

**I didn't test this. So use caution.**

- `-i`: input host(s)
- `-m`: module
- `-a`: module arguments
- `-u`: user
- `--ask-pass`: Ask for user password
- `--become`: become another user
- `--become-user`: new user
- `--ask-become-pass`: Ask for become user password

Comment: When I ran the `ping` command you suggested, I got an error on all the machines. This is the error I saw `machineC | FAILED => to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Yes, I forgot. You need `sshpass` since you are using password instead of keys. `sudo apt-get install sshpass`

Comment: Yeah I googled it and installed that.. And after that when I run the same ping command again, I get another error on all the machine. Here is example on one box -  `machineC | FAILED => Using a SSH password instead of a key is not possible because Host Key checking is enabled and sshpass does not support this.  Please add this host's fingerprint to your known_hosts file to manage this host.`

Comment: Can you try `export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` and run `ping`?

Comment: Yup ping command works now. Cool. So I can run the second command now on other file with fewer machines to test it out. If that works, then I can run it on the original file right?

Comment: Also when I try the second command, it gives me this error `ansible: error: no such option: --become`. I did `--help` and I don't see `--become` anywhere I guess. I am running `ansible 1.5.4` version and looks like cannot upgrade to newer version so need to find some solution with this version if possible?

Comment: That was an ancient version. `become` was called `sudo` before. Can you `man ansible` and see what the options are?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131942/discussion-between-user5447339-and-hellov).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to automate SSH copy / SSH login :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set password  [lindex $argv 1]

spawn scp -P 22 [lindex $argv 2] [lindex $argv 0] 

expect "*password:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"

expect eof
```

The `expect` command will wait for the string you give in arguments to be received.

You can iterate over your hosts from `hosts.txt` and run this script like this for each one :

```
./create_config.sh david@machineA:/opt/Potle/ouyt/wert/1/ somePassword functon.txt
```

If you dont have possibility to do SSH copy but only SSH, you can still send command with expect :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set password  [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ssh -p 22  [lindex $argv 0] 

expect "*password:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"

# expect the command prompt : change this if needed
expect "*$*" 

# execute some commands
send -- "echo 'some text to write to some file' > ~/some_file.txt\r"

# exit vm
send -- "exit\r"

expect eof
```

You can run this with :

```
./create_config.sh david@machineA somePassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sshfs: mount a machine, do what you want, unmount and pass to the next.